# Read Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter

i have a database in firebase and i am trying to read it using flutter. I found this tutorial here https://medium.com/flutterdevs/explore-realtime-database-in-flutter-c5870c2b231f
it looks pretty easy so i followed the steps. I added the read function in my code and when i run it i get this error here https://gyazo.com/a1cfe40527ad9908dcd4edfcd36d2cc9
if i search the error, i only get the solution to clean and flutter get but this doesn't work do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: can you share **pubspec.yaml**? Looks like you haven't added [firebase database](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database) package

Comment: firebase_database: ^3.1.6
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3

Comment: Update, if i look at the output i see this: https://gyazo.com/48658ccbdee4cd7fa4487a7bbabd76bd maybe this is why it isnt working?